# Most of my APIs are returning 400 bad request error while being called on frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, api, amazon-cognito, http-status-code-400

My API code is in python. It is hosted and works perfectly when called through postman. But when I try calling the same calls through my frontend react application, most of them respond 400 Bad request. Any idea as to why is this happening?
My application uses amazon cognito for authentication.

Comment: Most, but not all? Of those request s that processed successfully, is there a pattern between them? Anything on the server log?

Comment: Oh need to check that.

Comment: @Martheen I just checked all my APIs are returning 400 bad request, but they are being redirected to the server. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Try forwarding your API call to https://requestbin.com/ and see what are your app is actually sending

Comment: How to do that? I have never used it before.

Comment: You're essentially creating a "log anything" API on requestbin, then change your app API URL to requestbin, compare the logged app request to your postman request against requestbin, then adjust them accordingly

Comment: My GET requests were not working because I was sending `content-type: "application/json"` in headers which was not required. Now its working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My GET requests were not working because I was sending `content-type: "application/json"` in headers which was not required. Now its working fine.